# How to excecute a javaScript method from flex

Tags: javascript, facebook, actionscript, logout

I am trying to log out from facebook, not only loggin out form my app also from facebook too. I am using the Graph API Desktop version and i am coding with flex.

Is there a way to log the user out from app and facebook??? I think that maybe usign the javaScript method FB.logout() i could do it, but i dont know the correct way to do this.

I mean, i try:

> ExternalInterface.call("FB.logout()");

but it throws an error saying that externalInterface is no available in this container...

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Sounds like it could be that the allowScriptAccess setting, in the HTML in the page, doesn't allow ExternalInterface calls. http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16494.html

Comment: @Lars Blåsjö OK thanks for that info... do you know where i can set the allowScriptAccess = always???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that `allowScriptAccess` is set in the html. if you're using swfobject, you can set it via the `params` object. if you're using a plain `object` tag, set it as a nested `param` element, i.e.:

```
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
```

also, `ExternalInterface` builds the function call automatically, so you'll need to remove the invocation paranthesis `()`, i.e.

```
// Don't need the parens, EI will add them
ExternalInterface.call("FB.logout");
```

hope that helps! cheers.

Comment: thanks... the problem is that i donw really know how i could set this property, i mean, i dont know in which object i have to set it... thanks for the help!!!

Comment: are you using flex to generate the final html page? if so, you can go into the file at `<project root>/html-template/index.template.html` and look for the swfobject JS embed code. in that JS, there is a `params` object, which by default has a `allowscriptaccess` property set to `sameDomain`. you'll want to change that string to `always` if you are running the swf from a different domain, otherwise you can leave it alone.

Comment: Ok i think that i dont have luck cause i am not generating the final html page...

Comment: ok, so you created the final html page? are you using swfobject to embed the content?